# Batch code reading problem equal dash apostrophe

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd, substring

I got stuck with reading this script. I assume that `SET RAWDATA` is some sort of setting the parameters, but can someone tell me what is all about. Particulary I wonder about this syntax: `'='%`, `' ='%`, `=%`.

```
SET RAWDATA=%RAWDATA:~0,-1%
SET KEYS=%KEYS:~0,-2%
SET RAWDATA=%RAWDATA:  =%
SET RAWDATA=%RAWDATA:' ='%
SET RAWDATA=%RAWDATA: '='%
SET RAWDATA=NULL,now(),%RAWDATA%
```

Comment: This isn't bash. Maybe it's just data used as input of some other interpreter?

Comment: This definitely isn't bash. It's Windows batch programming. Not sure about all of the advanced operators though.

Comment: What you have got here is called [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) (first two lines) and [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) (all the other lines but the last one, which constitutes concatenation)...

Comment: We'll start with line `1.` which removes the last character from the variable value of `%RAWDATA%`. Line `2.` similarly removes the last two characters from the variable value of `%KEYS%`. The rest modifies the value of `%RAWDATA%`; line `3.` replaces all instances of two concurrent spaces with nothing, line `4.` replaces all instances of an apostrophe followed by a space with just an apostrophe, and line `5.` replaces all instances of a space then an apostrophe with just an apostrophe. Line `6.` prepends the string `NULL,now(),` to the remaining value of the variable `%RAWDATA%`.